# upgrade helm chart from another dir

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to run:
`helm install my-app ./helm/ --namespace=app-dev --set=app.name=my-app --values=./helm/my-app-values.yaml`
but I got this error:
`Error: YAML parse error on my-app/templates/deploy.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

I suppose that the helm install will look in the `/helm` directory and take that as a base

with `cd helm && helm install...` works as expected

Comment: Looks like you have an issue in your template manifest and not with the location of you are trying to upgrade your chart from.

Comment: with cd helm && helm install... works as expected

Comment: Please include the manifests if you can. there's a reference not being computed correctly. I do what you are trying to do all the time.